# enable cors on iis - load denied by x-frame-options: does not permit cross-origin framing

Tags: iis, iframe, cors, x-frame-options

There are several questions about that but I couldn't get the right answer yet. I give a short summary:

Company A has a website with an iframe in it. Company B gives the URL for that iframe. The user uses an application from Company B and with the settings the user chooses it sets up an URL which is delivered to the iframe from Company A.

However, the framing is not working yet because of x-frame-options. The error message is the following:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options:
>   http://www.myurl.com:8088/myPath?panel=panel&user=username
>   does not permit cross-origin framing.

I added

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

to my web.config and also tried to add

```
<handlers>  
    <remove name="OPTIONS"/>
</handlers>
```

without any success.

I got that suggestions from [this](https://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html) and [this](http://blog.aminjam.com/cors-support-for-iis8/) website to add CORS support on my IIS. As I mentioned above, without any success. I'm not that good in web development or IIS so maybe this question sounds stupid to you: Does Company A has to enable CORS or does Company B? Or both? And how? The suggestions I got from google didn't help yet.

Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message isn’t related to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header nor to `OPTIONS` handling, so it’s expected that the changes described in the question wouldn’t have any effect.

The cause instead is, the `http://www.myurl.com:8088` server’s sending an `X-Frame-Options` response header in responses for requests to `/myPath`. So if you don’t want the server to do that, you need to figure out what part of the server code is causing that `X-Frame-Options` response header to be added, and remove that code.

Comment: If I understand it right, company B has to do that, right? Are there some ways to easily figure it out?

Comment: Whoever controls the server running at `http://www.myurl.com:8088` needs to remove whatever is adding that `X-Frame-Options` response header in order for any code running at another origin to be able to frame that content. If you don’t control the server running at `http://www.myurl.com:8088` then there’s nothing you do can that’ll allow your site to frame that content. The entire purpose of `X-Frame-Options` is to block third-party sites from framing content when the content owners don’t want to them to. If there were some way for third-party sites to bypass it, that’d defeat the purpose

Comment: Okay, then I'll look for that X-Frame-Options part and remove it. Hope I'll find it. Is there a "typical place" for it? Or can it be anywhere?

Comment: One likely place is your IIS Web.config file. That’s probably the best place to look first.

Answer (score 0):

x-frame-options has been replaced by Content-Security-Policy and you can use it as following:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self' example.com *.example.net ;" />
    <add name="X-Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self' example.com *.example.net ;" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```